# matrix multiplication in matlab, using a for loop

Tags: matlab, loops, math, for-loop, matrix

I have to multiply `D=[cos(pi/18) -sin(pi/18); sin(pi/18) cos(pi/18)]` by `X= [0.80;0]` 9 times, using a for loop. I want to store the results in a table of the form: `X=zeros(2,10)`

I'm a bit lost.

Anders.

Comment: So you want to multiply a 2x2 matrix with a 2x1 matrix 9 times and get a 2x10 output. You're gonna need to be more specific than that for meaningful help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. Looping `D*X` (*2x1* matrix) *9* times doesn't give you *2x10* matrix.

Is this what you're looking for?

```
D = [cos(pi/18) -sin(pi/18); sin(pi/18) cos(pi/18)];
X = [0.80;0];
O = ones(1,9);
A = D*X*O
```

Output:

```
A =

 Columns 1 through 8:

   0.78785   0.78785   0.78785   0.78785   0.78785   0.78785   0.78785   0.78785
   0.13892   0.13892   0.13892   0.13892   0.13892   0.13892   0.13892   0.13892

 Column 9:

   0.78785
   0.13892
```

**Note**: Matrix manipulations don't need loop in Matlab most of the times

Answer (score 0):

IF the result of @jkshah's answer is what you want, use his answer (maybe change the `O` matrix to `O = ones(1,10)`). The reason MatLab is named like this is because it (or she :p ) is great with matrix operations and if you can you better avoid loops. In case you want to work with loops this is a way to do it:

```
D = [cos(pi/18) -sin(pi/18); sin(pi/18) cos(pi/18)]; % Input
X = [0.80;0];                                        % Input
A = D*X;                                             % The function
X = zeros(2,10);                                     % Initialize the result table

X(:,1)=A;                                            % Insert the result in 
                                                     % the first column

for i =1:9                                           % Iterate to fill the 2X10 table
    X(:,i+1) = A;
end
```